# How to convert tuples inside a list of lists to lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am new to python and I want to convert tuples into lists.
I have this list:

```
   allCombinations = [[('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'), ('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101')], [('CS106', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS106', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'), ('CS230', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH120'), ('CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'), ('CS107', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS106', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS107', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'), ('CS106', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('', 'CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'), ('', 'CS106', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS205', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH120'), ('CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'), ('', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('', 'CS106', 'ENG102', 'MATH101'), ('CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'), ('CS107', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'), ('CS106', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'), ('', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH101'), ('', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS106', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS107', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS106', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH120'), ('', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'MATH101'), ('CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'), ('CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'), ('CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'), ('CS106', 'CS215', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS106', 'CS215', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'), ('CS205', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'), ('CS107', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH101'), ('CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'), ('CS205', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120')],...]
```

and I want to convert the tuples to lists. I tried to do this

```
for x in allCombinations:
        _all = [list(x) for x in allCombinations]
    print(_all)
```

and this

```
_all= [list(elem) for elem in allCombinations]
```

which does not change anything,
and this

```
[[y for x in i for y in x] for i in allCombinations]
```

which gives me as a result

```
[[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER', 'CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER','MATH101']],...]
```

which is not what I want.
I guess I am missing something.

The output needed is like this:

```
[[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER','MATH101']],[...],...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `list-comprehension` + `map`

```
[list(map(list, l)) for l in allCombinations]
#[[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101']],[].. ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> allCombinations = [[('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'), ('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101')], [('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'), ('CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101')]]
>>> [[list(tup) for tup in sublst] for sublst in allCombinations]
[[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101']], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101']]]
```

Answer (score 3):

@Transhuman answer is good, but you can also use:

```
[[[*x] for x in x] for x in allCombinations]
# [[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'MATH101']], [['CS106', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS106', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS230', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH120'], ['CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'], ['CS107', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS106', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS107', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'], ['CS106', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['', 'CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'], ['', 'CS106', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS205', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH120'], ['CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'], ['', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['', 'CS106', 'ENG102', 'MATH101'], ['CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS107', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS205', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'], ['CS106', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'], ['', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH101'], ['', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS106', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS107', 'CS205', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS106', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH120'], ['', 'CS107', 'ENG102', 'MATH101'], ['CS106', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'], ['CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH120'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS106', 'CS215', 'ENG102', 'MATH120'], ['CS205', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'GER'], ['CS107', 'ENG102', 'FREE', 'MATH101'], ['CS107', 'ENG102', 'GER', 'MATH101'], ['CS205', 'CS230', 'ENG102', 'MATH120']]]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/7dafbc3ba1)

Comment: Nicely done. The "splat" operator (and its sibling the double-splat) is one of Python’'s subtleties.